# Database Engine Tuning Advisor "Failed to parse XML file"

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-tuning-advisor, dta

When loading a .sql file in Database Engine Tuning Advisor you get "Failed to parse XML file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Executing the DTA on the execute statement itself of the stored procedure, rather than the full 'Script to New Query Editor - Execute Stored Procedure' given by right clicking it."

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b9062b8-2f20-4028-8a94-e2166d41de5e/error-parsing-xml-in-database-engine-tuning-advisor?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 4):

Remove the "GO" at the end of the query (provided it's just a query).